# Inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)

Tags: java, java-8

I'm doing a project in which I have to negate the pixels of a PPM file (image).

I implemented my negate function as such:

```
public PPMImage negate() 
{
    RGB[] negated = new RGB[pixels.length];
    System.arraycopy(pixels, 0, negated, 0, pixels.length);
    RGB[] negatedArr = Arrays.stream(negated).parallel().map(rgb -> rgb.neg(maxColorVal)).toArray(size -> new RGB[size]);
    return new PPMImage(width, height, maxColorVal, negatedArr);
}
```

With the `neg(maxColorVal)` function being defined as this:

```
public void neg(int maxColorVal) 
{
    R = maxColorVal - R;
    G = maxColorVal - G;
    B = maxColorVal - B;
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
RGB[] negatedArr = Arrays.stream(negated).parallel().map(rgb -> rgb.neg(maxColorVal)).toArray(size -> new RGB[size]);

inferred: void
upper bound(s): Object
```

The error points at the map() function. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Also to add, RGB is an object that contains an R value, G value, and B value, which combine to make a color. Also, the pixel array is a protected variable of the PPMImage class, which is given to me.

Comment: If `RGB` is mutable, like your `neg` method suggests, there is no need to copy the array all the time (and doing so creates a dangerously wrong impression). On completion of your operation, all three arrays, `pixels`, `negated`, and `negatedArr` contain the same, modified values. If you stay with the mutable `RGB` value implementation, a simple `Arrays.stream(pixels).parallel().forEach(rgb -> rgb.neg(maxColorVal))` would do the entire job (and works with the original `void neg` method as well). If you don’t want to modify the original array, you have to clone the value instances.

Comment: Just wanted to say I really appreciate the formatting on this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correction :

Your `map` function expects a method that returns some reference type, but `neg` has a `void` return type.

Try to change your `neg` method to :

```
public RGB neg(int maxColorVal) {
    R = maxColorVal - R;
    G = maxColorVal - G;
    B = maxColorVal - B;
    return this;
}
```